# Snow Leopard: Who Owns /Library/Services?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions, services, automator

**Context for the Problem**

I've been downloading the new services and automator actions for the new Snow Leopard services menu, but I haven't been able to access them from the user profile I normally use (which is not an administrative user). I can access them from the administrative user.

**The Problem**

I've narrowed it down to the `/Library/Services/` folder having the wrong owner (I think). Here is the owner on my machine:

```
 mycomputer:~ user$ ls -l /Library | grep 'Services'
 drwxrwxr-x    6 root           admin   204 23 Jun 08:47 PDF Services
 drwx------   14 administrator  wheel   476  3 Sep 17:41 Services
```

`administrator` is the administrative user on my computer. I'm guessing that this folder should have another user. I need to know what the 'normal' owner for this folder is (assuming that it is not the administrative user) What does this command return on your machine?

Or am I off-base? Is it the group that is the problem? Is there something else I can do? I don't want to mess around with the ownership and group of the folder without knowing what they should be.

**Complete Answer**

The problem was both the ownership and permissions on `/Library/Services` and `/Library/Automator` They both were:

```
drwx------ administrator wheel
```

and they need to be

```
drwxr-xr-x root admin
```

I have no idea how they ended up being owned by the `administrator` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly would suspect it should be root/admin. I don't believe testing it by doing the chmod would do any harm, as this directory does not exist on a clean Snow Leopard install.

I also suspect if you want access to these script they should be in the Users/[username]/Library folder. Copy them there and give it a shot. It should give you a good indication of whether it will work or not.

**Update**

Thanks for pointing that out, late night and I got my commands wrong, I was referring to chown, not chmod.

Comment: I tried messing with `chmod` before, adding read and execute permissions, but no dice. I suspect you may be right about `root/admin` though.